# Google Analytics Goals & Funnels not working as expected

Tags: google-analytics

I am experiencing an extremely weird behaviour by the funnel Visualization inside my reports.

I set up a goal with the intention to measure my conversion rate in my shop. So I set up a goal of type destination. The value of my destination field is `^/config/paypal/success.*` and of type regular expression, because the URL could be something like `http://example.com/config/paypal/success?name=asdasd&date=asdad`

I have inserted a constant value of 24,99$ and activated the funnel.

Next I created 4 Steps:

- step1: `^/$`
- step2: `^/config/as34Sfs/page1`
- step3: `^/config/as34Sfs/page2`
- step4: `^/config/as34Sfs/page3`

Saved this and expected the funnel to work.

Adjusted the configuration alot of times to influence the results.
But they always output something different. I dont know how to test my expressions.

Right now the funnel exits 9/10 on the first step. One exit is `^/config/as34Sfs/page1` (WTF? shouldnt it just funnel to the next step then?) 1/10 goes down to step3 and is exited to `^/config/as34Sfs/page2` (WTF? AGAIN?)

I have a strange feeling that I am completely doing something wrong

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have added a $ at the end of every step. This seems to solve the problem. But the question remains.

EDIT2: A few hours later it seems to have WRONG data again?! whats going on!?

EDIT3: Any lonely soul reading this and wondering about the same thing, I think it has something to do with step1. It was marked necessary. When I unchecked it it all worked (With incoming pageviews in each funnel step but anyway evaluable data)